# Why does Hibernate require the list-index to be nullable?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a mapping similar to the following and it seems that the `index` column is not populated during the DB `INSERT` statement because the DB complains about `index` being `NULL`. However, if I make the `index` column nullable it works as expected.

```
<list name="someList">
    <key column="someFk"/>
    <list-index column="index"/>
    <one-to-many class="SomeClass"/>
</list>
```

Is there a way to force Hibernate to populate the `index` while inserting? I'm sure there must be a way but I've looked into the docs and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior can be explained through the prism of Hibernate `flush` operation order. If you take a look at the [`ActionQueue`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/engine/spi/ActionQueue.java) class, you'll see that the entity state transitions are executed in the following order:

1. OrphanRemovalAction
2. AbstractEntityInsertAction
3. EntityUpdateAction
4. QueuedOperationCollectionAction
5. CollectionRemoveAction
6. CollectionUpdateAction
7. CollectionRecreateAction
8. EntityDeleteAction

Now, the SQL INSERT statement is executed by the `AbstractEntityInsertAction` while the index is assigned through an UPDATE statement by the `CollectionRecreateAction`.

While I agree that it would be much more efficient to remove the UPDATE statement and populate the list index on INSERT, I think this change is going to require a considerable amount of refactoring work. You could open a JIRA issue for this, and mark it as an improvement.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. It's very surprising they took that road considering how important avoiding DB NULLs is. If I'd forgot to map the index I'd never know until I realize it later.